# jquery triggering click event on an anchor

Tags: jquery, events

i have something like

```
<a id="link" href="home/categoria/">link</a>
```

and i need to trigger a click on that and am using

```
$('#link').trigger('click')
```

nothing happens, any help? thanks

P.S.: I can't use location.href because this is for a facebook tab, and it doesn't work

Comment: Small note: you can achieve the same with `$('#link').click()`.

Comment: This should work -- open your browser's javascript console and check for errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triggering a click event in jQuery calls any `click` events that have been attached to the element. It doesn't simulate the user clicking on a link.

In your specific example, you could do:

```
location.href = $('#link').attr('href');
```

That would send the browser to the link in question.

Comment: thanks, i get that. the problem is i am doing this for a tab and the location.href doesn't work like it's supposed to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Facebook tabs. If you're trying to change an `iframe` from a separate frame, I've found that calling a function inside the `iframe` works when you can't do what you'd like directly. Obviously, this would only help if you control the code in the `iframe` as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to fire a link like that (although calling `.click()` like this will fire anything bound to that event).

If you want to navigate the user somewhere, use `window.location` instead.

Comment: thanks, i get that. the problem is i am doing this for a tab and the location.href doesn't work like it's supposed to.

Comment: So you're trying to trigger an event handler that's been bound to the click on that link? Should work, then. Can you give us more info, please?

Answer (score 1):

Just use ***[click()](http://api.jquery.com/click)***:

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // do some stuff

});
```

If you want to prevent the default redirect, use the `e.preventDefault();` as shown above.

Comment: sorry, that is not it. i want to trigger the click event remotely. thanks anyway

Comment: @Andre - Maybe you can update your question to be more precise to your actual situation?